# Azure worker role where are input endpoints declared?

Tags: azure

I have an azure worker role deployed to staging. (Azure sdk 2.2).

When I deployed it via Publish in Visual Studio 2013 I noticed that the number of input endpoints had increased from three to five!

When I looked in the Endpoints tab of the worker role properties, there are no input endpoints declared!

After doing a lot of googling with bing, I have been unable to find any reference as to where these input endpoints have come from.

I am trying to swap the instance from staging to production and it will not swap, as the number of input endpoints is different between staging and production. Both instances run fine, as I not using the endpoints anyway.

Any ideas where these endpoints are declared and how I can delete the ones I don't want?

Comment: While not exactly an answer to your question, do be aware of the fact that any time you make changes to your endpoints, it must be a new deployment and not an upgrade of an existing deployment. Don't let this point confuse your understanding of the situation any further!

Answer (score 1):

Endpoints are specified in ServiceDefinition.csdef (properties of the cloud project).  The extra endpoints you are seeing are because you published the project from VS2013 with "Enable Remote Debugging" selected (a new feature in VS2013 and Azure SDK 2.2).  The extra endpoints facilitate attaching the remote debugger. Deselect the option and republish.